# Prevent save the logs from laravel-schedule, laravel-notification in docker image

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-9, supervisord

I have created a docker image with a laravel 9 app by using this [repo](https://github.com/alcarazolabs/laravel-9-docker-image/).

The problem is that I'm not using laravel notifications or laravel-queue in my project I just did a simple webservice with some models and controllers.

This is the docker file:

```
FROM php:8.1.0-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Add docker php ext repo
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

# Install php extensions
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd memcached

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    lua-zlib-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    nginx

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy code to /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www

# add root to www group
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage

# Copy nginx/php/supervisor configs
RUN cp docker/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN cp docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini
RUN cp docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# PHP Error Log Files
RUN mkdir /var/log/php
RUN touch /var/log/php/errors.log && chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

# Deployment steps
RUN composer update
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN chmod +x /var/www/docker/run.sh

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/docker/run.sh"]
```

And this is the supervisor.conf content:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel = info
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[group:laravel-worker]
priority=999
programs=nginx,php8-fpm,laravel-schedule,laravel-notification,laravel-queue

[program:nginx]
priority=10
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/access.log

[program:php8-fpm]
priority=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -R
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/php-error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/php-access.log

[program:laravel-schedule]
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan schedule:run
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/schedule.log

[program:laravel-notification]
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan notification:worker
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/notification.log

[program:laravel-queue]
numprocs=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/worker.log
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

When I ran the docker image this starts throwing this logs:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/laravel-projects/laravel9-apirest$ docker run -p 80:80 laravel9app:1.0                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   INFO  Application cache cleared successfully.                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   INFO  Routes cached successfully.                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:06,713 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded                                                                                                                                                                  
2023-05-20 20:20:06,719 INFO supervisord started with pid 13                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2023-05-20 20:20:07,807 INFO spawned: 'laravel-queue_04' with pid 22                                                                                                                                                      
2023-05-20 20:20:07,817 DEBG fd 8 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 281472995279248 for <Subprocess at 281472995281936 with name nginx in state STARTING> (stderr)>                                        
2023-05-20 20:20:07,847 DEBG fd 9 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 281472995179584 for <Subprocess at 281472995282656 with name php8-fpm in state STARTING> (stdout)>                                     
2023-05-20 20:20:08,095 DEBG 'php8-fpm' stderr output:                                                                                                                                                                    
[20-May-2023 20:20:08] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 15                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:08,100 DEBG 'php8-fpm' stderr output:                                                                                                                                                                    
[20-May-2023 20:20:08] NOTICE: ready to handle connections                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:08,834 DEBG 'laravel-notification_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   ERROR  Command "notification:worker" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:08,835 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                                                 
2023-05-20 20:20:08,835 INFO success: php8-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                                              
2023-05-20 20:20:08,838 INFO success: laravel-schedule_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                                   
2023-05-20 20:20:08,838 INFO success: laravel-notification_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                               
2023-05-20 20:20:08,839 INFO success: laravel-queue_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                                      
2023-05-20 20:20:08,840 INFO success: laravel-queue_01 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                                      
2023-05-20 20:20:08,841 INFO success: laravel-queue_02 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                                      
2023-05-20 20:20:08,843 INFO success: laravel-queue_03 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                                      
2023-05-20 20:20:08,844 INFO success: laravel-queue_04 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                                      
2023-05-20 20:20:08,849 DEBG 'laravel-notification_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                     
  ⇂ notifications:table                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  ⇂ queue:work                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  ⇂ schedule:work                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:08,851 DEBG 'laravel-notification_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:08,867 DEBG fd 19 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 281472994823184 for <Subprocess at 281472994821408 with name laravel-notification_00 in state RUNNING> (stdout)>                      
2023-05-20 20:20:08,974 DEBG 'laravel-schedule_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:08,975 INFO exited: laravel-notification_00 (exit status 1; not expected)                                                                                                                                
2023-05-20 20:20:08,976 DEBG received SIGCHLD indicating a child quit                                                                                                                                                     
2023-05-20 20:20:09,009 DEBG 'laravel-schedule_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                         
   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:09,014 INFO spawned: 'laravel-notification_00' with pid 47                                                                                                                                               
2023-05-20 20:20:09,018 DEBG fd 14 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 281472995179056 for <Subprocess at 281472995179536 with name laravel-schedule_00 in state RUNNING> (stdout)>                          
2023-05-20 20:20:09,556 DEBG 'laravel-notification_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   ERROR  Command "notification:worker" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:09,557 INFO exited: laravel-schedule_00 (exit status 0; expected)                                                                                                                                        
2023-05-20 20:20:09,558 DEBG received SIGCHLD indicating a child quit                                                                                                                                                     
2023-05-20 20:20:09,559 DEBG 'laravel-notification_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                     
  ⇂ notifications:table                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  ⇂ queue:work                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  ⇂ schedule:work                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:09,563 INFO spawned: 'laravel-schedule_00' with pid 56                                                                                                                                                   
2023-05-20 20:20:09,566 DEBG fd 19 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 281472994821456 for <Subprocess at 281472994821408 with name laravel-notification_00 in state STARTING> (stdout)>                     
2023-05-20 20:20:10,042 DEBG 'laravel-schedule_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:10,043 INFO success: laravel-notification_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                               
2023-05-20 20:20:10,043 INFO exited: laravel-notification_00 (exit status 1; not expected)                                                                                                                                
2023-05-20 20:20:10,044 DEBG received SIGCHLD indicating a child quit                                                                                                                                                     
2023-05-20 20:20:10,061 DEBG 'laravel-schedule_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                         
   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:10,066 INFO spawned: 'laravel-notification_00' with pid 59                                                                                                                                               
2023-05-20 20:20:10,069 DEBG fd 14 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 281472994822848 for <Subprocess at 281472995179536 with name laravel-schedule_00 in state STARTING> (stdout)>                         
2023-05-20 20:20:10,592 DEBG 'laravel-notification_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   ERROR  Command "notification:worker" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:10,593 INFO success: laravel-schedule_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                                   
2023-05-20 20:20:10,594 INFO exited: laravel-schedule_00 (exit status 0; expected)                                                                                                                                        
2023-05-20 20:20:10,594 DEBG received SIGCHLD indicating a child quit                                                                                                                                                     
2023-05-20 20:20:10,595 DEBG 'laravel-notification_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                     
  ⇂ notifications:table                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  ⇂ queue:work                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  ⇂ schedule:work                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:10,600 INFO spawned: 'laravel-schedule_00' with pid 62                                                                                                                                                   
2023-05-20 20:20:10,603 DEBG fd 18 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 281472994823232 for <Subprocess at 281472994821408 with name laravel-notification_00 in state STARTING> (stdout)>                     
2023-05-20 20:20:11,071 DEBG 'laravel-schedule_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2023-05-20 20:20:11,072 INFO success: laravel-notification_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)                                                                               
2023-05-20 20:20:11,072 INFO exited: laravel-notification_00 (exit status 1; not expected)                                                                                                                                
2023-05-20 20:20:11,073 DEBG received SIGCHLD indicating a child quit                                                                                                                                                     
2023-05-20 20:20:11,090 DEBG 'laravel-schedule_00' stdout output:                                                                                                                                                         
   INFO  No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

The application runs without problem but the problem is that inside the file:
/var/log/supervisord.log of:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel = info
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
```

this being populate with this logs and I can't stop it.

I tried setting /dev/null the paths for logs in the next programas but the same problem remains.

```
[supervisord]
 ..
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:nginx]
...
stderr_logfile=/dev/null
stdout_logfile=/dev/null

[program:php8-fpm]
stderr_logfile=/dev/null
stdout_logfile=/dev/null


[program:laravel-schedule]
...
stdout_logfile=/dev/null

[program:laravel-notification]
 ...
stdout_logfile=/dev/null
```

My enviroments variables are in production and debug mode in false

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

I'm not docker expert specially working with laravel queues or notifications but I would like to disable it and prevent fill the docker image with a lot of logs that  I can't stop.
I would like to know some ideas from this community guys to fix this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: this is my laravel 9 app: https://github.com/alcarazolabs/laravel9-apirest thanks

Comment: Two typical best practices are to only run one process in a container, and to log to stdout rather than a file.  Can you remove supervisord here, run Nginx in its own container, and avoid logging to files entirely?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes I want stop logging those logs because my app never uses schedule, notifications or queues. Please help

Comment: Here are the full logs: https://pastebin.com/wKNvvAjQ

Comment: due the big mount of logs from those programas I just change logleve to critial instead bebug or info and of this way only critial logs shall be saving and this reduces the big noise [supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel = critical

Comment: You could just remove what you don't need from the `supervisor.conf` file...